# How to write "\" character using cat() in R?

Tags: r, escaping, cat

I am trying to use the cat() function in R to write data to a file. I would like to write a "\" character to the output, but it seems that the cat() function interprets this as a formatting command. Any ideas on how I can write this in the middle of formatting commands (e.g. "\t\t\t \ \n")?

Comment: Does it help when you write two? (Which is a common way of escaping in other languages.)

Comment: The best description of this in the help pages is not seen at `?character` but rather at `?Quotes`.

Answer (score 4):

In R, because `\` is a metacharacter you need to use `\\` to print a single backslash in `cat()`.  One is an escape character.  This can easily be verified by calling `cat("\\")`,

Here are a few examples:

```
> cat("a\nb\tc")       ## standard output
a
b   c

> cat("a\\nb\\tc")     ## prints the control characters in the string
a\nb\tc

> cat("a\\nb\\t\\c")   ## prints the control characters in the string, 
a\nb\t\c               ## and one backslash before "c"

> cat("a\tb\tc\t\\\nd") ## read as "a<tab>b<tab>c<tab>\<newline>d"
a   b   c   \
d
```

Also, I've found [this wikibooks link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) to be quite useful for learning about text processing with R.